# How to install and configure phpmyadmin on linux running with Nginx

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

please help me installing phpmyadmin on ubuntu running with Nginx

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty easy, just execute below command

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

to get more info, read [Install and configure phpmyadmin](http://www.contents.co.in/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-running-with-nginx/)